# Error with golang "undefined (type string has no field or method)"

Tags: go, hash

i use this library [golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt](http://golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt) to hash password and compare hash with password but I having problem see below:

main.go file

```
package main

import (
        "./hash"
)

func main() {
        password := "passwd"
        hash := "hhhhhhhhaaaaaaaaaassssssssssshhhhhhhhhhh"

        check := hash.CheckPasswordHash(password, hash)
}
```

hash/hash.go file

```
package hash

import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

func HashPassword(password string) (string, error) {
        bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)

        return string(bytes), err
}

func CheckPasswordHash(password, hash string) bool {
        err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hash), []byte(password))

        return err == nil
}
```

if you run this:

```
$ go run main.go
```

It will show this error:

> ./main.go:11:15: hash.CheckPasswordHash undefined (type string has no
>   field or method CheckPasswordHash)

why this error?

Comment: You have a variable named `hash` which is shadowing the package named `hash`. Also, try to avoid relative package imports.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `main`, your variable name `hash` contains a long string. So it shadows the package name `hash`. You should rename one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

In main.go file Change hash variable to other name (Do not use variable with the same package name)

thanks "Adrian"